# Xamarin Forms Databinding "." separator

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm struggling with databinding in Xamarin Forms. Here's why, what I expect to happen from the following XAML statement:

```
IsVisible="{Binding Path=UserContext.IsLoggedOut}"
```

Is - That the property is bound to a child object of the View Model. Now either this isn't supported in Xamarin Forms or I am missing a trick.

If this is not supported in Xamarin, where it is supported in WPF, then what are we supposed to do in order to propagate nested objects? Flattening the View Model is making me write reams and reams of inelegant code.

Comment: How does UserContext look like?

Comment: UserContext is a property of the viewModel class. UserContext object has a property called IsLoggedOut

Comment: could you paste the code?

Comment: Its too much code to paste in but really I don't see why inspecting the UserContext object would make much difference. I think its an issue with Xamarin.Forms not supporting nested objects in databinding, but I haven't had this confirmed to me yet

Comment: It is definitely supporting nested binding. That's why I wanted to have a look at your code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nested properties are supported, like other pretty complex expression as well:

You can test it:

**Xaml**

```xml
<StackLayout Spacing="20">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Subproperties: " HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="15"></Label>
    <Label Text="{Binding Item.SubItem.Text}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="15"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Indexer: " HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="15"></Label>
    <Label Text="{Binding Item.Dictionary[key].Text}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="15"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Array Indexer: " HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="15"></Label>
    <Label Text="{Binding Item.Array[1].Text}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="15"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**Page**

```cs
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ItemModel Item { get; }

    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Item = new ItemModel();
        BindingContext = this;

    }
}

public class ItemModel
{
    public ItemSubModel SubItem { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ItemSubModel>  Dictionary { get; set; }
    public ItemSubModel[] Array { get; set; }

    public ItemModel()
    {
        SubItem = new ItemSubModel();
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, ItemSubModel>
        {
            {"key", new ItemSubModel()}
        };
        Array = new [] {new ItemSubModel(), new ItemSubModel() };
    }
}

public class ItemSubModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; } = "Supported";
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: You're correct must be something to do with my code. Will update.

Comment: OK not sure what exactly was causing the issue, but I re-implemented everything from scratch and everything is working now lol. Thanks Sven-Michael!

Comment: Make sure your properties have public getter and setter or you will mysteriously not see any data.  This is the case for two-way bindings at least.  I haven't tried mapping a one-way binding to a property with only a getter but I suspect that it might work.

Comment: How to do databinding when ItemSubModel has subclass which is a list? 'public class ItemSubModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<ChildModel> ChildList{get;set;}
}'

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying in Xaml. Try removing 'Path'.

```
IsVisible="{Binding UserContext.IsLoggedOut}"
```

However more importantly, what is your `BindingContext`? For the above code to work you would need the `BindingContext` to be set to class `Foo`, which has a property called `UserContext`, which itself has a property `IsLoggedOut`.

Have a look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) as well

Comment: BindingContext is set to my View Model in code. The View Model has a property called UserContext, which itself has a property called IsLoggedOut. In Xamarin Forms this propagation doesn't seem to work nor is it documented anywhere I think. AllDayer can you get this sort of thing to work?